# Include .java files as java source files in Android Studio to remove red circle with "J" on them

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Today after update android studio my source folder in project marks as below("J" inside a red circle mark). How can I fix it? I tried clear caches, re-import project, use `gradlew clean build`, but it doesn't help.
[image]

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

def AAVersion = '3.0.1'
dependencies {
   ......
}

apt {
    arguments {
     ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you upgrade your version of Gradle and your Android Gradle plugin? It should have warned you about it when you opened the project after update and offered a fix.

Comment: yes, i did it. a project builds well

Comment: I see that your project doesn't have the typical Gradle directory structure. Can you please add your module's build.gradle file to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some magical solution while playing with this

There are two possible solution you can try to make it correct (tricky one)

1.Replace this in your build.gradle file

```
java.srcDirs = ['src']   to   java.srcDirs = ['src/com']
```

2.Create a subdirectory inside `src` name it whatever you want, I prefer name it `java`  like

```
src > java
```

move all your java package in to it and change the

```
java.srcDirs = ['src']   to   java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
```

These are the tricky solutions. It can be considered as a bug in Android Studio that it is not considering the java source set if it is the root of `src` directory but compiles fine.

After doing all the necessary changes sync your project with gradle and your yellow directory will be magically turned into blue.

**Note : Even you have them in root there will be no effect on compilation as per my experience. Only Studio will not mark them as java sourcesets in IDE.**

Answer (score 4):

I solved it just closing the project from android studio and remove the project from recent project. Re-import the project, it worked. If any one facing for android project he/she can try this. Thanks

Comment: Close Android Studio and delete .idea and .gradle folder from project structure and start Studio again.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Project Structure in Android Studio (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on Windows/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> on macOS)
2. Under modules Header over the left of the window, look onto right side of it , You will get to see three tabs one of which is Sources ,Select it.
3. There, you will find the structure of your project which you have imported or might have created by self.
4. Go for the src folder of it and wait for the sources link above that dialog with many others to get avail to apply onto it,grab it.
5. Apply and OK
6. Problem Solved.

Comment: it looks like they change it in the latest versions of AS because I am not able to find it (but I am also using Mac - this might change something)

Answer (score 1):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66758 and should be fixed in Android Studio 0.5.1, which is out now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open build.gradle file (one in module, not in project)
2. As you open it you will see "This folder does not belong to a Gradle project. Make sure it is registered in settings.gradle." message, and "Add now..." link in upper-right corner
3. Click "Add now" and Gradle will do its job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue after maybe switching branch or after taking pull. Then you can fix it by going in to File>Invalidate Caches/restart.