# Java files have a red circle with J in it (android studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

I downloaded a project from GitHub, in which me and a friend are working on. Everything was working fine and all of a sudden a red circle with a "J" in it was on the Java files' icons and the run app button become grayed out. Please help me!

Comment: right click on directory containing the java package and 'Mark Directoy As'->sources root. the folder should turn blue i think. and the package folders will have a little blue dot

Answer (score 3):

*I hope you have already found a workaround, but if not/for future reference:* 
I assume we 're talking about this icon: [image].
 If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22267041/2486904) answer (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904052/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-intellij-red-circle-on-bottom-left-corner-of-fil) post) don't seem to be a solution for you, then you should probably go for [Configuring Content Roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html) (docs based on IntelliJ, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826963/2486904) answer should conform the docs to Android-Studio).